# Rails: undefined method Error when scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, scope, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    # Associations
    has_many :issues
    # Instances
    def has_issues?
        issues.resolved.exists?
    end
end
```

and an Issue Model:

```
class Issue < ApplicationRecord
    # Associations
    belongs_to :user
    # Scopes
    scope :resolved, -> { where(:resolved => true) }
end
```

If I now call in my view something like:

```
unless current_user.has_issues
```

I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in Controller#index
>   undefined method `has_issues' for #<User:0x72dd7c0>

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scopes are methods that you call on the class (e.g. `User.has_issues`) or an ActiveRecord::Relation (e.g. `User.where(...).has_issues`). You cannot call a scope method on an instance of the model. If you want to get information about an instance of the model, you should use an instance method, not a scope:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :issues

  def has_issues?
    issues.resolved.exists?
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your updated code? (Note that my code has a question mark at the end of the method name, per Ruby convention, so make sure to account for that.)

Comment: When you call the method are you calling `has_issues?` or `has_issues`?

Comment: I forgot to append the questionmark, when I called the method. Thanks for your help!